# How to blacklist a PCI device so a system can boot?

Tags: 10.10, blacklist, pci, modules

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on someone's computer which it had a 'Connexant Fusion 878A' PCI card installed, the card is problematic, I had to unplug it just to use the Live CD.

Now my question is how to know which module to blacklist, so he can use the card in Windows and override it when he boots into Ubuntu.

There's a twist, I can't plug it and `lsmod` it because it won't let the system boot up even in 'Recovery Mode'.

- Kernel: 2.6.35-22

Comment: What's the card's exact model name?

Comment: It is a low-end card with no brand at all, the only visible name is the chipset's name which is 'Connexant Fusion 878A'http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Conexant_Fusion_878A

Comment: On the wiki you linked to it says that that particular chipset is supported by bttv kernel driver and modules (http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Bttv). The module name is bttv,  so stick it in one of /etc/modules.d/blacklist-*.conf files, update your initrd and hopefully it will work :).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. If everything works fine, you'll have to re-write the comment as an answer so I can mark this thread as SOLVED.

Comment: @RedaLazri, did you get this resolved? If the above comment worked, you can answer & accept your own question to get this off the "unanswered questions" list :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: Yes, please close this. The guy threw the card, so I can't test the answer. Sorry.